# check if duplicate exists in a column and do something sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a email address column in my database, I want to check if there are duplicates do TASK FAILURE PATH and if there is only one entry do TASK SUCCESS PATH

```
    DECLARE @DuplicateCount int=
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM tblWebPortal_Login
                WHERE Email = 'abe@abeprakash.com' 
                GROUP BY email
                HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
            );
            select @DuplicateCount 

if @DuplicateCount is null
TASK SUCCESS PATH
else
TASK FAILURE PATH
```

The issue i have is @DuplicateCount is returning null if there is only one entry and if there is no email address present. i.e., TASK A is done for email address which is only present once (which is correct) however TASK A is done if email is some garbage data (Which is wrong)

I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: What do you mean by TASK FAILURE PATH and TASK SUCCESS PATH? What exactly you want to do. There are multiple ways to do something. Please provide full clarification so that we can help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the `count()`. The `GROUP BY` clause isn't necessaray, if you filter for only one e-mail address. And the `HAVING` clause is generating the `NULL`s.

```
DECLARE @DuplicateCount integer = (SELECT count(*)
                                          FROM tblWebPortal_Login
                                          WHERE Email = 'abe@abeprakash.com');

IF @DuplicateCount = 1
BEGIN
  -- TASK SUCCESS PATH
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- TASK FAILURE PATH
END;
```

Like that the success path is only entered, when the e-mail address exists exactly once. If it doesn't exist at all or multiple times, failure path is entered.

Comment: This is exactly what i did but used count(email) instead of count(*)

Comment: @Abe: `count(*)` and `count(email)` won't make a difference here, as `email` cannot be `NULL` because of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

First of all avoid group by and having that is not necessary in your coondition

Second dont use count(*) use count(email)

```
DECLARE @DuplicateCount int=
            (
                SELECT COUNT(email)
                FROM tblWebPortal_Login
                WHERE Email = 'abe@abeprakash.com' 

            );
            select @DuplicateCount 

if @DuplicateCount is null
TASK SUCCESS PATH
else
TASK FAILURE PATH
```

Comment: why not use count(*) and use count(email) ? Thank for the solution i have tested it and it works.

Comment: `count(*)` and `count(email)` won't make a difference here, as `email` cannot be `NULL` because of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Abe - the count(email) to check specific count, can you please upvote my answer?